# Usar video em wordpress sem iframe

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Eu estou com uma dúvida que pode ser bem iniciante, há algum modo de exibir videos do youtube em uma pagina wordpress sem usar Iframe? Há varias discussões dizendo que o Iframe é uma péssima idéia, há algum modo de fazer sem Iframe?